# How to identify "Wireless Hosted Network" inside GetAdaptersAddresses results

Tags: windows, winapi, wifi

I'm enumerating the MAC addresses of a computer using the `GetAdaptersAddresses` Win32 API which returns a list of all adapters present on that computer.
When the user turns on WiFi, the list contains three new elements:

- XXXXXXXXFCD8: Actual WiFi (Intel)
- XXXXXXXXFCDA: Microsoft Virtual WiFi
- XXXXXXXXFCDA: Microsoft Virtual WiFi

The start of the MAC addresses has been redacted but they all are equal except for the last digit that has a single bit flipped. I know those two virtual WiFi cards come from the [Wireless Hosted Network](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/windows/desktop/NativeWiFi/about-the-wireless-hosted-network) feature but I cannot ask every user to turn that off.
As I'm only interested in the actual WiFi card, I'm trying to find a way to reliably identify the two "Microsoft Virtual WiFi" cards. I looked at the various members of the `IP_ADAPTER_ADDRESSES` structure which gave me the following.

Real WiFi:

```
FriendlyName = Connexion réseau sans fil 4
AdapterName = {57DA33EE-F8E2-4F2C-B989-12EEB680CD64}
Description = Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless-AC 7260 #2
PhysicalAddressLength = 6
PhysicalAddress = 0000XXXXXXXXFCD8
Flags = 01E5
IfType = 71
TunnelType = 0
OperStatus = 1
```

First Virtual WiFi:

```
FriendlyName = Connexion réseau sans fil 5
AdapterName = {7E6DCD1E-BFBB-41AF-A4B1-467C2FFB5D5E}
Description = Microsoft Virtual WiFi Miniport Adapter #3
PhysicalAddressLength = 6
PhysicalAddress = 0000XXXXXXXXFCDA
Flags = 01C5
IfType = 71
TunnelType = 0
OperStatus = 2
```

Second Virtual WiFi

```
FriendlyName = Connexion réseau sans fil 6
AdapterName = {CC263A05-8034-46C9-9060-FC353D9BBBCB}
Description = Microsoft Virtual WiFi Miniport Adapter #4
PhysicalAddressLength = 6
PhysicalAddress = 0000XXXXXXXXFCDA
Flags = 01C5
IfType = 71
TunnelType = 0
OperStatus = 2
```

As you can see, apart from the `Description`, which appears not to be localized, I cannot see any difference between those three network cards.

Do you know of another API that would allow me to check if a given adapter originates from the "Wireless Hosted Network" feature ?

If not, do you think that searching the `Description` member for `Microsoft Virtual WiFi` would be a time resilient way to do it?

Comment: In your output the flags are not the same.

Answer (score 1):

The `Flags` are different between the adapters

The real WiFi has these flags:

> 0x01E5 (0111100101)

The virtual adapter has these flags instead:

> 0x01C5 (0111000101)

As you can see, they differ by 1 bit.

Microsoft does have a set of API functions for working with [Wireless Hosted Network](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/NativeWiFi/about-the-wireless-hosted-network). You could try querying the hosted network's information and try to match it up to your adapter information. For instance, [`WlanHostedNetworkQueryStatus`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/Wlanapi/nf-wlanapi-wlanhostednetworkquerystatus) will give you the GUID of the Hosted Network's virtual device.

Also, Microsoft has a [`WlanEnumInterfaces()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/wlanapi/nf-wlanapi-wlanenuminterfaces)
 function for determining the available WiFi network interfaces and their GUIDs. The virtual Hosted Network interfaces are not included in this list, according to the documentation.  So you can try using that as a kind of filtering mechanism, too.

Comment: Yes, the flags are different, but the extra bit is also set on other legitimate interfaces, so it can't be used to identify the WHN interfaces.
I'll look at the two other APIs, though, they look promising.